# Resizing Bitmap to fit other Bitmap

Tags: android, bitmap

I have problem with displaying bitmaps. I have a bitmap (marker) that is loaded from resource and placed on the map and I download bitmap (avatar) from the server with specific dimensions. Then I place the avatar in the center of the marker. The result is that on one phone every thing works fine, but on other the avatar is larger then marker.

What should I do?

Comment: you need to merge two bitmaps and then put that single bitmap as marker

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do this way Hope this helps you

```
googleMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().title(markerData.get(USER_NAME))
                            .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromBitmap(combineImages(BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.your_pin_marker_from_resorece), bitmapAvatar)))
                            .position(new LatLng(Double.parseDouble(markerData.get(USER_LAT)), Double.parseDouble(markerData.get(USER_LONG)))));
```

**Combile Images**

```
public Bitmap combineImages(Bitmap frame, Bitmap image) {
         Bitmap bitmapCreate = null;
            Bitmap bitmapScale = null;
        bitmapScale = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(image, convertSizeToDeviceDependent(45), convertSizeToDeviceDependent(40), true);

        bitmapCreate = Bitmap.createBitmap(frame.getWidth(), frame.getHeight(), Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);

        Canvas comboImage = new Canvas(bitmapCreate);

        comboImage.drawBitmap(bitmapScale, convertSizeToDeviceDependent(7), convertSizeToDeviceDependent(7), null);
        comboImage.drawBitmap(frame, 0, 0, null);
        if (frame != null) {
            try {
                bitmapScale.recycle();
                frame.recycle();
                image.recycle();
                bitmapScale = null;
                frame = null;
                image = null;
            } catch (Throwable e) {
            }
        }
        return bitmapCreate;
    }


public int convertSizeToDeviceDependent(int value) {
        DisplayMetrics dm = new DisplayMetrics();
        getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(dm);
        return ((dm.densityDpi * value) / 160);
    }
```

Comment: Could you explain me the convertSizeToDeviceDependent(int value) method ?

Comment: As there are so many resolution and screen size in Android device. So If I add directly 45 hard coded it will not give same out put in all device. That's why this method will convert 45 as device resolution and screen size.